# Using row value from dataframe to query columns in second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to pass the values from `df['A']` to determine null value count and unique value count for the column title in `df2` that has the row value from `df1`.

```
df
A    B    C
AA   1    2
AB   1    3
AC   1    2


df2
AA    AB    AC
X     Null  F
Null  R     F
Null  R     Y
```

The code should output as follows:

```
df1
A    B    C    NullCount UniqueCount
AA   1    2    2         1
AB   1    3    1         1
AC   1    2    0         2
```

I've considered defining a function and then applying it to `df1`, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to go.  I am new to python so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `v0.20`, you can use `agg` + `merge`:

```
df

    A  B  C
0  AA  1  2
1  AB  1  3
2  AC  1  2

df2

    AA   AB AC
0    X  NaN  F
1  NaN    R  F
2  NaN    R  Y
```

```
df3 = df2.agg(['count', 'nunique']).T
df3['count'] = df2.isnull().count(1).values - df3['count']

df.merge(df3.rename_axis('A', 0).reset_index())

    A  B  C  count  nunique
0  AA  1  2      2        1
1  AB  1  3      1        1
2  AC  1  2      0        2
```

Alternatively, you could combine the `count` computation into one step with a lambda:

```
df3 = df2.agg([lambda x: x.size - x.count(), 'nunique']).T
df3.columns = ['NullCount', 'UniqueCount']

    A  B  C  NullCount  UniqueCount
0  AA  1  2          2            1
1  AB  1  3          1            1
2  AC  1  2          0            2
```

Note that you might need to convert the string "Null" to `nan`. You can do that with a `replace` call:

```
df2 = df2.replace("Null", np.nan)
```

Comment: happy holiday, my friend :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is great.